# Shifting of saddle point of lagrangian when changing the active constraint

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

An informal statement of my problem is as follows:

I have  a lagrangian $L1$ defined over a constraint set and my algorithm 'walks' to the saddle point through alternate minimizations and maximations. I call the path the algorithm takes 'Walk1'.

I now shift the inequality constraint that is active in L1 to a new position and walk to the new saddle point of this lagrangian $L2$. The inequality constraint is active here as well. I call this path 'Walk2'.

My question is, is there a way to relate 'walk1' with 'walk2' to the changes in the active constraints ?

Comment: What do you mean by "shift the inequality constraint that is active in L1 to a new position"?

Comment: The inequality constraint ,say $x <= 20$, is active when the algorithm converges to the saddle point in $L1$  This inequality constraint is now shifted to $x <= 17$ in $L2$.